# Scene loading finishes (90%) in 1 frame, but isn't isDone until 3 frames later

Tags: unity, loading, scene, async, addressable

I am loading scenes async using addressables like so

```
    AsyncOperationHandle<SceneInstance> asyncOperation = Addressables.LoadSceneAsync(sceneReference, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
            while (!asyncOperation.IsDone)
            {
                if (asyncOperation.PercentComplete < 0.9f)
                {
                    Debug.Log($"\t{sceneReference.Name} Loading progress: {asyncOperation.PercentComplete * 100}% frame:{Time.frameCount}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log($"\t{sceneReference.Name} Loading complete but still in loop?: {asyncOperation.PercentComplete * 100}% frame:{Time.frameCount}");
                }
                yield return null;
            }
```

It reaches 90% on the first frame, which, based on my reading should mean it's finished loading.

However, the console spits this out: [image]

So it's not actually finishing the load until 3 frames later.

I'm at a loss to figure this out. Shouldn't it exit without a single iteration through the while loop? My game shows a very brief flash when swapping between screens, as I've already unloaded the previous scene and there is this 3 frame gap before the new scene appears.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you unloading the previous scene before the async operation reports that it's done? The whole point of doing this asynchronously is usually so that you can keep playing in the old scene or showing a transition state while the next scene is readied.

Comment: @DMGregory We didn’t go that route initially because we are targeting very low end devices, and didn’t want multiple scenes open at once. I suppose we should have tested it though before making the assumption this would be a problem. We currently have business requirements to not have a transition screen during this particular load. Any idea why it’s getting stuck for a few frames? I’m curious to understand this problem, even if it turns out it’s fine to do the unload after.

Comment: I don't think it's "getting stuck", I think the progress percentage is just not linear (the docs do not guarantee that it must be). There's some amount of work at the end of the load, like deserializing or wiring up references, that's difficult to accurately predict and divide into neat percentage figures. The engine isn't just sitting twiddling its thumbs for two frames for no reason.

Comment: Have you considered using `allowSceneActivation` to stop the new scene from rendering until the load has completed and you've unloaded the previous scene, to avoid having two running simultaneously, while still not allowing a gap in between?

Comment: No I haven't but this approach makes sense. Definitely will try it out and update you later on. What's the best way to reach out to you? I'm worried the comment section will become very bloated. I guess just make a new post on this question and tag you? @DMGregory

Comment: Don't reach out to me - anyone on this site can help you. I just happen to have been the first one to comment so far, but I don't "own" your case or anything like that.

Comment: I am a coworker of @complexproblem. We successfully got our load to seem quite seamless by unloading after the load is complete. This works great. However, we are running into an issue where the two scenes are open at the same time for a couple frames. The issue is that we have the same singletons in both scenes conflicting with each other. We need to rethink how these singletons interact, and how scripts can find the correct one during this transition time. Just wanted to update here for others, or see if anyone has faced similar issues. Maybe singletons are coming back to bite us.

Comment: @AdamB You can employ an intermediary loading scene, or a long living 'container' scene that other scenes are additively getting loaded along with.

Comment: I don't understand your assumption here. It of course doesn't finish loading at 90%, it finishes at 100%. Why would you assume otherwise?

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin In unity’s documentation it says 90% is finished loading and 100% is active.

Comment: The whole operation is a "loading operation". You are confusing yourselves.